# Removing files without a specific extension

Tags: bash, unix, command-line, sh

I have a list of files - some ending with .txt and some not. How do I run a command to delete all files not ending in txt?

I tried:

```
rm *.[^txt]
```

but that did not work?

Comment: For what it's worth, your attempt matches files whose name has a dot as the penultimate character and anything except `t` or `x` as the ultimate character (the second `t` is redundant).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using bash, you can turn on the `extglob` shell option:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Then you can use the extended pattern syntax `!(pattern)` to match all filenames that do not match `pattern`. First, test it with `echo`:

```
echo !(*.txt)
```

Assuming that the output is the files that you want to delete, pull the trigger:

```
rm !(*.txt)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
rm !(*.txt)
```

It should delete all files not ending with .txt

do `shopt -s extglob` first to ensure extended pattern matching features are enabled .
`shopt -s` will show you all enabled optional shell behaviors .

Comment: I'm using terminal on my mac. I got "-bash: !: event not found"

Comment: use shopt -s extglob first then. I have  updated the answer

Comment: It's hardly specific to OSX; I don't think `extglob` is enabled by default much anywhere.

Comment: @tripleee  yes,you are right. May be I enabled this on my system long time ago, so rm command just worked fine for me. I have updated the answer.